# Find the closed form of the gamma function related series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I see a possible way of computing  the series by using integrals, but I wonder if it possible
to avoid the use of them, to get a neat evaluation by only using series.

*Compute*
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\log\left(\frac{\displaystyle \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\left(\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\right)^2}\right)$$

*And here is a supplementary question*

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\psi^{(0)}(\alpha n)\log\left(\frac{\displaystyle \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\left(\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\right)^2}\right),\space \alpha >0$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decomposing the sum into two parts, with $n=2k$ and $n=2k-1$ and recombining them, we can rewrite it as
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\frac{\Gamma^3\left(k+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(k-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma^3\left(k\right)\Gamma\left(k+1\right)} \tag{1}$$
Next, using the recursion relation for the [Barnes $G$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html), $G(z+1)=\Gamma(z)G(z)$, a *finite* analog of the sum (1) can be computed:
$$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln\frac{\Gamma^3\left(k+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(k-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma^3\left(k\right)\Gamma\left(k+1\right)}=\ln\frac{G^3\left(N+\frac12\right)G\left(N-\frac12\right)G^3\left(1\right)G\left(2\right)}{G^3\left(\frac32\right)G\left(\frac12\right)G^3\left(N\right)G\left(N+1\right)}.$$
Now to compute the original sum $S=S_{\infty}$, it suffices to use the known asymptotics of $G(z)$ for large argument. This gives
$$\ln\frac{G^3\left(N+\frac12\right)G\left(N-\frac12\right)}{G^3\left(N\right)G\left(N+1\right)}=O\left(\frac1N\right),$$
and in turn implies
$$S=-\ln\left(G^3\left(\frac32\right)G\left(\frac12\right)\right)=-\ln\left(\pi^{\frac32}G^4\left(\frac12\right)\right)=-6\zeta'\left(-1\right)-\frac{\ln 2}{6}-\frac{\ln \pi}{2}.$$
The final step uses the known evaluation of $G\left(\frac12\right)$, see the formula (19) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html).

Comment: (+1) for the answer. However I wonder if using Barnes-G function is not an overkill at this question.

Comment: @Chris'ssis In my opinion it's just the opposite. Every time one has infinite products of gammas, this is the most natural thing that comes to mind. And it belongs to the same world as Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\log\left(\frac{\displaystyle \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\left(\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\right)^2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{A^6}{2^{1/6}\sqrt{\pi e}}\right)$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html